# How to limit target platforms when building Android app (gradle) from command line?

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

I have an Android app, which I can build from the command line using the Gradle Wrapper (`gradlew`). I can execute only certain portions of my build (for example: `./gradlew assembleDebug`). However, this always builds for all four platforms (x86_64, x86, arm64-v8a, armeabi-v7a).

For my inner dev loop, I'd like to be able to build faster--do all the things, but just for x86 and Debug, so that I can quickly build something and try it out on an emulator.

How can I scope my Android builds to just x86 and Debug, using the command line?

(I don't want to alter the gradle project files, so that I can also easily build the "real", full packages for testing on a device.)